# What are the guidelines for reviewing?

Tags: support, faq, review

- What are the guidelines for reviewing?
- What should one avoid doing when reviewing?
- How can it happen that one is suspended from reviewing, and what are the implications of this?
- If I've been suspended from reviewing, where can I see the reason(s) for this?

Answer (score 11):

The site offers several review queues that make helping moderate this community more streamlined. For details on these queues, see the FAQ on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/): [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work).

When you decide to review, please do it in the spirit of helping moderate this community.

- **Do not turn it into a game or a competition.** Yes, there are badges, stats, and leaderboards, but don't make it your sole objective to perform well in the review queues.  While it might seem harmless, empirically it is very hard to avoid negative effects on the quality of reviewing if you do so, and it can create conflicts.
- **Do not rush it.** Care should be taken when evaluating posts for review. Yes, if one is used to doing it, then some posts can be evaluated quickly, but please continue to be diligent.
- **Reviews should be conducted in line with MSE's community standards.** This means you should not:

  (a) ignore rules or guidelines for questions you like, or

  (b) close questions that you dislike, but do not violate any rules or guidelines.

  For example, if you consistently vote to leave open questions with insufficient context, your review privileges will be revoked. Similarly, if you consistently vote to close questions simply for being low level, your review privileges will be revoked.

  There is more leeway when taking review actions outside the review queues (on the main/meta site itself), but in the review queues please try to take a middle-of-the-road position. If you don't want to do this, or don't know what this is supposed to mean, that's not a problem: there is no obligation to review.
- **Review with an open mind.** Go to the queues in the spirit of making a good faith effort to evaluate posts that are presented to you. Of course, it is alright—and can even be desirable—to narrow down the posts via the filtering-options, and to skip posts one does not feel comfortable reviewing, or where one does not know what to do.

  However, do not skip through the queue just to find one specific post you want to review. You also should not side-step casting votes for "ideological" reasons by skipping posts. For example, if you go to the Close Votes review queue with the intention to definitely only cast votes to close, or to definitely only cast votes to leave open, then this is not really in the spirit of the review queues.

Failure to comply with these guidelines can result in a review suspension. You will then be blocked from reviewing for a certain period of time. Other than that, the site can be used normally; this is not an account suspension.

The decisions to review suspend are made by the moderators. We have a set of indicators and thresholds, and discuss it among each other in cases of doubt. These decisions can be questioned, as can any moderator action.

**Finally, in the case that you have been suspended from reviewing,** please note that you can see a notice regarding the suspension in the drop-down menu when you click the review queue icon in the top bar.