# No Review Queues available. Why?

Tags: support, review

I checked the review queues tab but it keeps on showing me "There are no review queues available to you". However it is not so on this Meta site. Why is that? When would they be available?

Comment: I dunno, but you might be review banned for choosing "Looks OK" on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1184108) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1184445), and "Leave open" on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1183527) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1183854)...

Comment: @AndrewT. Got it. Would be more careful in the future. Cheers :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the moderators establish that the reviewing of a user is not in line with what is expected from reviewers, we revoke the reviewing privilege of this user for some time.

If you are in this situation, you should find some information regarding this with a brief explication in you inbox and/or the page you mentioned. [I am not sure how this is shown.]

For instructions on how to review please see:

[What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29764/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing)

Comment: This answer is obsolete. Currently bans are mentioned explicitly. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351118/improved-experience-for-users-with-review-suspensions