# Why does it show 'No review queue available for you'

Tags: support, review

I was looking for some reviewing stuff and this happened
[image]

It shows no review queue available for you, why is that so and when can I expect them back?

Just for reference, I haven't been reviewing much lately.

Comment: Did you fail a review test recently?

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi no, i haven't failed any

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Review Queues available. Why?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30072/no-review-queues-available-why)

Comment: @amWhy I don't think that's right. That's what it used to say, but right now it explicitly says you have a review suspension if that is the case.

Comment: The explicit message might be found in a users inbox, @MattSamuel.

Comment: @amWhy The question you're linking is out of date. I have a review suspension right now and it doesn't look like that. You click the drop down and it says "Review privileges suspended until Oct 25." See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351118/improved-experience-for-users-with-review-suspensions).

Comment: I couldn't know that, @MattSamuel  Thanks for the information.

Comment: Is that a persistent phenomenon?

Comment: @quid sorry for late reply, no this is the first time and it's normal again now. Thanks!

Comment: @quid should I delete the question since it's a duplicate without an answer?

Comment: It isn't really a duplicate. The answer there does not apply now. If it already went away I'd assume it was a glitch. However, I think on meta you actually might still get it as there you have no queues (for lack of points) IIRC.

Comment: @quid thanks and I have realised meta is not my place ,I am not much active there. ;-)

Comment: I just note a deleted comment of yours that actually might explain  it; I'll check later. You said you had exhausted your votes and this might block you on the grounds that without votes you arguably cannot review effectively.

Comment: @quid yes, that would be it, thanks for pointing out. I don't know what is happening to me, can't figure thing out easily :(

Comment: Don't worry. It was not a very obvious thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all users have access to all review queues at all times; this is the systems way to inform you that currently you cannot access any of the review queues. That bit was likely in a way obvious, but bear with me.

A few reasons why you cannot access the queue:

- As mentioned in comments by amWhy one can be suspended from reviewing and historically this was indicated like this as I explained here earlier https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30073/ However, as Matt mentioned this changed very recently (see [Improved experience for users with review suspensions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351118/improved-experience-for-users-with-review-suspensions)) and nowadays you would receive an explicit indication that you are suspended. That is, you are not  in this case.
- If you have exhausted your votes for the day you are blocked from reviewing at least in certain queues too. (I am at this point not certain regarding the exact restrictions, that is which votes block which queues.) From deleted comments it seems that you were in this case. It could be that it is also shown when one exhausted the 20 posts limit in all the queues, I am currently not sure about that.
- You do not have enough points.  One needs to pass a certain threshold of points to have access to the queues, which is not the same for all queues.
  However, for users that do not have access to any queue at all the button is not even shown, thus usually you will not see this in that case. However, on the meta site, where not all queues are available, this is shown for users that have access to some yet not all queues on main.

There may still be other cases but that are the ones that came to mind.

The indication will go away once you can again access the queues; in the case of missing votes this means usually the next day. (There can be corner cases I think, as some votes are 'restored' upon delete, but that's likely a detail and I am not sure how the logic interacts.)