# Closed question after several months.

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I was browsing through some of my answers. Then I've found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2767612/what-is-a-probability-of-coin-being-loaded). It has been closed after more than 7 months.

Now my question: Is there a reason why such questions can be closed after such a long time?  Shouldn't be there a time limit for closing questions?

Best regards,

callculus

[image]

Comment: There is no statute of limitations on bad questions, even if there is some agreement about historical quality vs. quality of the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I know. But I didn´t find a good reason why a question should be closed after such a long period.

Comment: Technically, it is because the post has an accepted answer, so that the closed posted is not deleted automatically. Some users had to vote to delete the post (or some users could edit and improve the posts, then reopen it).

Comment: [older posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734773/fracdydx-3y2-3-general-solution). Someone please delete it.

Comment: @ArcticChar OK, the question cannot be deleted. But why should it be closed after such a long time?

Comment: Why shouldn't it? The best situation is of course that some users go take a look and initiate further action (delete or reopen). But if no one does that, then it seems natural to keep it closed.

Comment: But the question (with contribution of the questioner) was clear, the answer was clear. In my view there is no action needed anymore after such a long time. So question can be closed without any reason?

Comment: I don't understand: are you suggesting that closed post should be reopen automatically after some time? That seem to do more harm than good.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this meta post: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30163

Comment: @Jack Thanks for the link. I totally agree with [your answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30163/144421).

Comment: You did not add a "specific question" tag to this, so I'm reluctant to post an Answer treating it as such.  However seven months is not "such a long time" and there's no implication that a "question can be closed without any reason."  Indeed your work on the problem seems to start with untangling the ideas the OP put into Comments below the Question, so perhaps the best course of action would have been to help the OP with an edit that put those efforts into the body of the Question.  The problem does really revolve around why those efforts did not succeed.

Comment: @Arc I don't think call is suggesting closed posts be reopened after some time; rather, that open posts should be immune to closure after some time. That is, once a post has been open for some number of months, it should no longer be possible to close it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, I misread that. Thanks.