# Why does it take 5 close votes, to close a question?

Tags: discussion, closing

I had a similar question a few days ago.
There I was banned from review queues, because I seem to disagree on close votes to much. 
I promised to never review again, but I made a little experiment and visited again the close votes.

I just voted to not close a question, when it was (in my opinion) not fair to close.
And because I am not a fan of closing question anyways, I skipped the really bad questions.

Now I am banned again from review queues.
But what have I done wrong?

If you do not want an other opinion on closing a question. Then don't ask for it. That is what I wrote in my last 'rant'.

I really do not get it. 
When there is no appreciation of an other opinion then to close these questions, then why does it take 5 votes?

It seems it is 100% clear which questions deserve to be answered and which not.
I think the one who answers the question should decide which questions he answers.

(I know that there is this meta-post on bad audits, but no one is ever going to read this, when I post there. Also it does not really fit anyways, because I did not fail an audit. At least it did not tell me. If the system is automatic, then it should be fixed. And if a human is behind it after all, I have a pretty good idea who.)

Comment: I don't understand, if you refused to cast closed vote even for really bad questions, then why visit the closed vote review queue at all?

Comment: Why did you choose to Leave Open low-quality questions like [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3193058/is-it-possible-to-integrate-int-01-fracxnx5-dx-int-01-fracxn), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3188179/divergent-positive-decreasing-series-a-n-proof-sum-a-n-exp-fraca-n) and [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3186736/how-do-i-solve-the-for-the-base-of-an-exponential-modular-arithmetic-equation)? These are simply taken from your review actions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/439383/cornman?tab=activity&sort=reviews).

Comment: @TheSimpliFire All of these questions have two or three answers. In an ideal world every one who asks a question shows his own effort. But sometimes you simply do not know how, or you know that what you tried is wrong or bad. So why write it down? If you can answer a question you should not close it.

Comment: @ArcticChar Because I think, that most closed questions do not deserve to be closed.

Comment: And the most really bad questions can be edited with MathJax. Only questions, that do not make any sense, or can not be answered, deserve to be closed (in my opinion).

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Your comment is based on the false presumption that everyone shares your *personal opinion* of "low quality question", how to best use the site, etc - all highly subjective matters.

Comment: You should cast the close votes according to the question as is now, but not according to what it could becomes. If it is bad, just vote to close. Vote to reopen uif it is edited to an acceptable standard.

Comment: @ArcticChar As for your first comment, why don't you ask the same question to all the reviewers who robotically vote to close everything?  Keep in mind that their are diverse views in the community on these highly subjective matters. "Popularity" of any particular view wxes and wanes over the years.

Comment: Where did I say that I would not ask otherwise? @BillDubuque

Comment: @ArcticChar You have not, and I cannpt read your mind (nor should I have to).

Comment: I have not done I lot of things in the comment thread too, so what? @BillDubuque

Comment: @ArcticChar Your should strive to be more understanding of those whose opinions differ from yours - that's what.

Comment: @BillDubuque My first comment is to ask for clarification why someone would leave open a question that is "really bad". That is orthogonal to "strive to be more understanding of those whose opinions differ from yours".

Comment: @ArcticChar Keep in mind, that not everyone who asks here, is familiar with MathJax. So why should not take the community care of these 'low quality' questions. Also most of these questions still have great answers. So why close them in the first place. I liked to edit questions, but then people from the community started harrassing me for failing audits and now these banns...

Comment: @Cornman The problem is that we have a different definition of a "really bad" question. To me, a question without mathjax is not a question that is "really bad".

Comment: @ArcticChar For me a 'really bad' questions, is a question which can not be answered on MSE. Like 'What is the best breakfast to study math?' or 'What is the best book to learn topology?'. For me a question without mathjax is not really bad either. It is a questions which should be edited. Even when it is cryptic, like 'what is the integral of x^2 in the interval of [1,3]' would not be a bad question in my opinion. I would edit it and leave it open, because the question is clear. It might not be an interesting question, but that should not be considered anyways, when voting to close.

Comment: So from your previous comment and the post, it seems you will not vote to close quesions that cannot be answered on MSE?

Comment: @ArcticChar No, there you misunderstood me. That are the only questions I would vote to close. Or these kind of really, really bad questions, where it is obvoius, that one is only interested in someone doing the work for him.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm the human behind your review ban.

You were consistently voting to leave open posts that were in clear violation of community standards. Review isn't asking for your opinion on whether closing a question for insufficient context is fair, it is asking you to close questions that have insufficient context.

Put another way, a police officer who consistently sees someone breaking the law and does nothing will not be a police officer for long, regardless of his views. The review queue is a space for enforcement, not activism.

Please see [Guidelines for reviewing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29764/12952) for more information. In particular,

> Reviews should be conducted in line with MSE's community standards. This means you should not (a) ignore rules or guidelines for questions you like, or (b) close questions that you dislike, but do not violate any rules or guidelines. For example, if you consistently vote to leave open questions with insufficient context, your review privileges will be revoked. On the other hand, if you consistently vote to close questions simply for being low level, your review privileges will be revoked.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Will start reviewing once my bann is over.

Comment: But some people disagree with the insufficient context nonsense. You're imposing your will and not allowing them to review, silencing their opinion?

Comment: @MattSamuel I can not see if you are talking to me, or to Alexander Gruber.

Comment: @Alexander Gruber Also I do not get why I get banned from every review queue, when you disagree with my close votes. Seems unfair. But hey, who am I to judge your opinion, right?

Comment: This is what the automated review audits are for. You don't need anything in addition to that.

Comment: @Bill: I thought that sometimes the community is wrong, and then the moderators need to step in and override their action. No?

Comment: @Asaf Do you have something specific to say about *this topic* vs. some tangent?

Comment: @Bill: I am just surprised when you say that moderators should behave one way, but you behaved in a completely opposite way when you had a diamond. I'm just trying to frame your criticism to those users who are not versed in the history of the site...

Comment: @Asaf You have *seriously misunderstood* my viewpoints in the past, so one should not attempt to make inferences from such. But this has very little to do with this thread,. I have stated my opinions on *this matter* above.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What I do not get is, why I get banned, for not voting to close questions, which were closed later on. You ask for 5 close votes. If a question is that bad, you do not need every single ones opinion on that specific question. It gets closed anyways.

Comment: What is even more rediculous to me, is that Alexander Gruber took into account, that I skipped close worthy questions. I mean... come on, really?

Comment: @Cornman "Do not cherry-pick via skip." https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29765/468350

Comment: @XanderHenderson Why does the skip button then exist? Is this not the way to abstain from something. Also I would not say, I abused this. But I see. The review queues are something I really should stay away from. There are some hardliners here, who want it in a specific way. So what, I just wont review anymore and spare me all this trouble. It is just annoying, to review and see, that there is no appreciation at all. Now that I do not gain any benefit, and just do it for fun, I can also safe these few minutes a day, and do something really productive.

Comment: @Xander Please do explain the relevance of quoting a *single user's* opinion on this matter.

Comment: @Cornman The next several sentences following the quoted bit above explain how the skip button should be used: "If you review, please, try to review the posts that are presented to you. Of course sometimes one feels badly placed or unable to evaluate a post. Then one should skip. But skipping through the queue to find specific types of posts is not really in line with the ideas of the queues."

Comment: @Xander Again, that's nothing but one user's *opinion*.

Comment: And not what I have done.

Comment: @MattSamuel yes, users with views at the extremal ends of the spectrum are not allowed to  use the review queue as a lever to push their own views on the community. (Goes for all other extrema too.) We want something like  middle of the road reviewers. Those with unusual views are free to voice them and to express them in other ways, just not in the review queue.

Comment: @quid *Seriously*? So anyone who thinks differently from you is "unusual" or "extreme". So much for moderators being "moderate" and helping to seek compromises. I'm glad I live in a country where someone can't randomly take away my right to vote by (mis)characterizing my views as "unusual" (or similar nonsense). The platform is supposed to be founded on *democracy* - not dictatorship. Excuse me while I attempt to extricate my jaw from the floor...

Comment: @BillDubuque as explained we put a break on the activities of people with views to the extreme ends whose actions might tear the community further apart. On the rest, the "votes" to close just are not votes in the sense of an election, especially not when carried out in the review. There is a difference between being allowed to hold and to voice an opinion and to take actions according to ones opinion. IIRC in the biggest city of your country it's not even allowed to walk around with an open can of beer. There are plenty of rules there and not following them may or may not have consequences.

Comment: I'm given to understand I could, within limits, denounce a perceived absurdity of that rule without problems, which is good, yet what I could not, at least not necessarily, do is stroll around drinking beer. [Personally I would not stroll around drinking beer, as that's not my style, but that it's not allowed is weird. If I am wrong on that rule replace it by something else. In any case I once witnessed at another place in that country somebody being refused beer in a restaurant, with a meal(!), because it was Sunday. Felt pretty absurd, with a lot of good will I can imagine some rational.]

Comment: Either way leaving this tangent behind, a society/community  being organized in  a democratic way is not at all the same as everybody being *free to act* in whatever way they please, it's not even overly correlated. @BillDubuque

Comment: @quid Poor analogy. Better analogy: in the USA no can take away our right to vote simply because they think we vote in "unusual" or "extreme" ways. This is exactly what has been done above. **This violates the basic *democratic* principles that this platform (and country) were founded upon.**

Comment: @BillDubuque it seems to me, at least in some states, the right to vote is taken  away if one is found to have violated some rule.

Comment: @quid Nowhere in the USA can the right to vote taken away because of how one has voted in the past. Imagine the possible abuses that could lead to were it true.

Comment: @BillDubuque if one does not follow the rules of the community  the right to vote can be taken away. Yet again, reviews and eve votes to close more generally are not votes in a democratic sense. One is supposed to provided an evaluation. A moderately fitting analogy would be reviewing a paper for a journal. The reviewer has some leeway but they are bound by editorial policy. If somebody disagrees with that policy they can say so, obviously, but they should not use their status as reviewer to undercut it. In such a case an editor might decide not to solicit that reviewers opinion anymore.

Comment: That's also not a good analogy.

Comment: @BillDubuque maybe so, but it's way better than comparing close-reviewing a post to electing a president (or other politicians).

Comment: We'll have to disagree on that too. Journals are not founded on the same democratic principles as this platform (for better or worse).

Comment: It's rather ironic that the highest voted comment here is an untruthful ad-hominem remark by a "moderator" that has nothing to do with this thread, Do other mod's support such behavior?

Comment: @Bill: I'm confused. I am *not* a moderator?

Comment: @Asaf I have no interest in engaging with someone who behaves so nonconstructively. Alas, some things never change....

Comment: @BillDubuque It's ironic that you bring up USA in this context. Many other countries do **not** implement [felony disenfranchisement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felony_disenfranchisement).

Comment: @BillDubuque Most of the friction I have with you does not come from our differences of opinion. Your, should I say "pompous", rhetoric is what makes it difficult for people around you to take the effort to understand why your opinion is what it is. Remember, debate club rules don't apply here. To most of us "ad hominem" and "strawman" are meaningless as terms, and **lesser** breaches of conduct (given also that you seem throw those terms around apparently expecting others to fold) than your overt missives.

Comment: @Asaf What are we to take away from your comment about the community being wrong? Is it some shaded jab at Bill's moderator past, or are we to take it at face value? (The implications of taking it at face value are...not nice...)

Comment: @user1729: The actual point is that moderators try to keep the community within certain bounds. Yes, we are informed by our "personal opinions", but also by the arguments of the community. My problem with Bill's argumentation is form, as pointed by others here, and specifically that Bill is always agreeing that "action needs to take place", but refuses to discuss when it should take place and how. Adding insult to injury, this so-called libertarian was a pretty tyrannical moderator, and repeatedly overrode community votes based on his own personal opinion.

Comment: @Asaf Just checking :-)

Comment: @Asaf  Could you please have the courtesy to *quote* me rather than to continue to put your words into my mouth. All of the clickbait that you have written about me above is very far from my personal views. I don't try to speak for you. Please extend me the same courtesy.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen If you seriously think that I "throw those terms around apparently expecting others to fold" then that is yet another example of how greatly you misunderstand my motives.  And there is nothing at all "pompous" about striving to find good inclusive compromises that will maximize the amount of expertise we can attract to the site, and maximize the utility of the site to the general public.

Comment: @Bill: Unfortunately, I have neither time nor the inclination to dive into your history on meta at the moment. Suffices to say, however, that you have expressed your views that moderators should not interfere with community decision, and yet singlehandedly reopened closed questions where you thought the closure was "unjustified abuse by the community". In that case, I ask that you extend to the current moderators the same courtesy in letting us use our powers where we think that some community members are misusing theirs.

Comment: @Asaf You're comparing apples to oranges. The immense MK bullying fiasco doesn't compare to anything we are discussing here. Please try to stay on topic. This is not the place to exercise your grudges about past moderation (about which you had very incomplete information since you were not a moderator).

Comment: @Bill: Let's not get off topic. The point is the same. You can't claim that moderators should *always* stay on the sidelines until the last moment and let the community handle all the moderation possible, but at the same time do the opposite. The incongruity between your words and your actions make all your use of debate club terminology absolutely moot. You either feel that you're exempt from the same criticism you passed on everyone else, or you can't see that you should be held to your own standards. And in doing so, you've barred yourself from being part of a constructive conversation.

Comment: @Asaf No. I claim moderators should be exception handlers. And that's exactly what I did in the MK fiasco (which was by far the biggest incident of bullying of a user that has ever occurred on this site),. Again, you don't know all the details since you were not a moderator. You are making wild guesses based on very incomplete information. But again, this is way off-topic here.

Comment: @Bill: And Alex has acted as an exception handler in this case. So what's the problem? In both cases, the community has exercised its own rights to self-moderation, and in both cases a moderator has observed something that they felt was an exception to the rule, and exercised their power to try and correct the course of action.

Comment: @Asaf The problem is that this did not require any exception handling, and this  "exception handling" is not being done fairly. Did you not read what was written above?

Comment: @Bill: Yes. That is your opinion. And we are disagreeing on this, and not for the first time. But then again, I also don't think that there was any exception handling in the case of MK. So... I guess we're both wrong? In any case, we are getting to an impasse, and I have other things to do at the moment. Best of luck in your future endeavors. Or perhaps I should say endeavours, since I'm living in the UK for over a year now...

Comment: @Asas, Glad to see your drop this way-off-topic tangent that you initiated above,. This is not the place to discuss prior moderation events.

Comment: @BillDubuque Since when are your catchphrases like "stooping to new lows", "unilateral", "extreme abuse" ... attempts to strive for an inclusive compromise? The incongruity! May be "pompous" is not the most fitting adjective in the English language, but... you have single-handedly alienated half a dozen community elected moderator in your campaign to become a dictator.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  That's a very strange definition of "dictator" that you seem to have. I find it baffling that you are surprised of being accused of "stooping to new lows" given your behavior. Do you think that others will take no offense at your incessant personal attacks? In the last month alone you have accused I and other prolific teachers of being rep-whores motivated by ego, and you even broke the rules of your mod contract to try to invoke private data (our of context) to support your strange arguments.  If that doesn't count as "stooping to new lows" then what does? Please introspect.

Comment: I do not want to interrupt your discussion about previous events, but I think in a math forum, or question-answer-site you might consider that not the community (or me) is wrong, but the rules might be. What is so wrong with not closing some threads, that you have to be banned from review queues (without clear notification that you are and why). I do not see anything wrong with reopening questions, which were closed. If it were the other way around, I could see the point, but nothing harmful is done, by letting these questions open, so I do not see the point of doing that.

Comment: In any case, I hope that some mod will clean up the above tangent that Asaf initiated. Maybe some folks needed to vent, but it is not good to leave this stuff around ("broken windows"). There is already too much confusion on such matters (that someone wrongly thinks I wanted to be a "dictator" is one of the most outrageous claims I've ever seen here).

Comment: @BillDubuque You are comparing apples to oranges. Only one of has been suspended four or five times on the site - basically for general toxicity. My accusations are a recent thing due to my frustration. Your offensive rhetoric, on the other hand, has been a standing joke since, like forever. Rep-whoring? Only one of us, when accidentally reposting answers, will come up with excuses like "this is an evolved version". (The other one will turn the dupe answer to CW). Only one of us tried to overrule several fellow moderators. Do you really want me to give other math gems and key ideas??

Comment: Yes, I may be "stooping to new lows". I am not the first person you have managed to drag away from their normal disposition.

Comment: @Jyrki Since you continue to post bizarre unfounded ad hominem attacks there will be no further replies from me. Please have the courtesy to not ping me any further.