# It is Midterm Season! Please help out with the review queues.

Tags: discussion, review

It is, apparently, midterm season, and the site is currently being inundated by a large number of problem statement questions, duplicate questions, and other low-quality questions, which means that the review queues (particularly the "Close" review queue) is experiencing quite a backlog:  there are currently over 500 questions in need of review.

This is a friendly reminder that anyone with sufficient reputation is able (and encouraged!) to wade into the review queues and help with the janitorial duties of site moderation.  For those unfamiliar with the process, the review queues can be access from a drop-down at the top-right of nearly every page on the site.

[image]

Information on the process of reviewing can be found in the [Help Pages](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/review-queues).  Further advice can be found [in a FAQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29764/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing).

Comment: Will definitely do, thanks.

Comment: Reviewing 20 questions may sound like a lot, but most of the cases are fairly clear-cut, bearing in mind the question policy on this site. It's not actually that much effort compared to the 'low season', where the cases were much more nuanced and/or involved material beyond one's expertise. 'Take your time and use your best judgement' is the best advice I can give.

Comment: whenever i have free time,i used to visit Cure group in chatroom for delete and closed  the low quality question . Also,im trying my best  to review the  low quality questions in the newest post section

Comment: TBH, the review process revamp of a few months ago, which seemed to provide more tools and flexibility to deep reviewers, made it more clumsy and confusing for this "casual reviewer". *sigh* Oh well, I respect Xander a lot - I guess I'll get myself back up to speed with the new format.

Comment: I get the influx, but what is the question here?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Meta is sometimes used to make announcements that are relevant to the community.

Comment: The question could be summarized, @Tyma, as if you are a user with review privileges in the close queue, or any other queue, and you aren't regularly reviewing, would you consider doing so, please?

Comment: Any improvement since the announcement @XanderHenderson? From what I see, the close votes are currently at $403$ and remained below $420$ whenever I checked, but perhaps it hasn't improved in the peak hours yet?

Comment: I was wondering what the reason for the flood was. I noticed a large increase in PSQs, but didn't know where they came from.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon How do you check for the number of questions waiting to be reviewed

Comment: @LalitTolani (On PC) On the main site, next to your profile picture ,reputation and badges (once you log in), there are some buttons which lead to menus. Depending upon whether the privilege is available or not, there will be one that looks like a checklist with a tick mark on it. If you click on it, the title of the pop-up menu is "review queues" and you get a list of queues where questions are fed in and reviewed. Just above these queues, is a small link called "all queues". Clicking on it tells you how many questions are there in each queue at the time of your checking.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon As of writing this comment, there are $570+$ questions in need of review.